How to Set Up SSH Passwordless Login for SELF
I have a situation where a program requires to open an additional SSH login session to its own SERVER.
For example - I have a server with IP 10.100.1.100 and when I run the said script it tries to ssh 10.100.1.100 with the same user which prompts for password. I want to escape the said prompt.
I tried using the following steps however I am unable to successfully configure the same.
Server - LINUX RHEL

ssh-keygen -t rsa
mkdir ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
cp ~/.sshid_rsa.pub ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
chmod -R 700 ~/.ssh
chmod -R 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys


You have copied your ssh public key as a file in authorized_keys directory, but's that not how authorized_keys works. authorized_keys is a file not a directory. remove the directory and create the authorized_keys file by doing cat ~/.sshid_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys and modify the rights of it to 600 as you've done previously on the directory.

Aah, it worked. A silly mistake !! Thanks!!

You create directory, it need to be file:
mkdir -p ~/.ssh
cat  ~/.sshid_rsa.pub >>~/.ssh/authorized_keys

And do not forget to remove directory ~/.ssh/authorized_keys beforehand

Aah, it worked.
A silly mistake !! Thanks!!
